# Short and elegant way to do typecasting in C++?

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

Say I want to store the size of a `std::vector` in an `int` I have the following options, to my knowledge:

```
int size = vector.size(); // Throws an implicit conversion warning
int size = (int)vector.size(); // C like typecasting is discouraged and forbidden in many code standards
int size = static_cast<int>(vector.size()); // This makes me want to gouge my eyes out (it's ugly)
```

Is there any other option that avoids all of the above issues?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184721/discussion-on-question-by-makogan-short-and-elegant-way-to-do-typecasting-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question just like you've asked. The other answers say why you shouldn't do it. But if you still want to have this, use this function:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

inline int toInt(std::size_t value) {
    assert(value<=MAX_INT);
    return static_cast<int>(value);
}
```

Usage:

```
int size = toInt(vector.size());
```

`toInt` asserts if the input `value` is out of range. Feel free to modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to frame challenge this question. You shouldn't *want* a short and elegant solution to this problem.

Casting in any language, including C++, is basically the programmer's equivalent to swearing: you'll do it sometimes because it's easy and effortless, but you shouldn't. It means that somewhere, somehow, your design got screwed up. Maybe you need to pass the size of an array to an old API, but the old API didn't use `size_t`. Maybe you designed a piece of code to use `float`'s, but in the actual implementation, you treat them like `int`'s.

Regardless, casting is being used to patch over mistakes made elsewhere in the code. **You shouldn't want a short and simple solution to resolve that**. You should prefer something explicit and tedious, for two reasons:

- It signals to other programmers that the cast isn't a mistake: that it's something intentional and necessary
- To make you less likely to do it; and to instead focus on making sure your types are what you intended, rather than what the target API is expecting.

So embrace the `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast` style of writing your code. Instead of trying to find ways to make the casts easier, find ways to refactor your code so they're less necessary.

---

If you're prepared to disregard all of that instead, then write something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
T as(U && u) {
    return static_cast<T>(u);
}

int size = as<int>(values.size());

bool poly_type::operator==(base_type const& o) {
    if(this == &o)
        return true;
    if(typeid(*this) == typeid(o)) {
        return as<poly_type const&>(o).value == value;
    } else {
        return false;
     }
}
```

That'll at least reduce the amount of typing you end up using.

Comment: Here's another reason to use casting. You are writing a mathematical function that works in a continuous space (floats), that continuous space is then mapped to a discrete space (ints). So you need to compute values using floats and doubles, but then access memory using integers. Which one way or another requires you to take the value of a float and interpret it as an integer.

That is less of a design flaw and more of a property of the kind of computations you are doing.

Comment: @Makogan Fine; but you'd still normally hide that kind of detail behind an API layer, like `void* get_memory_for(float x, float y)` or something like that. Write `static_cast<intptr_t>` once and then call that function a bunch of times everywhere else.

Comment: That is not practical when you have to constantly do this for almost anything you code.

Think about computer graphics, there is a constant conversion between primitive types, especially floats and integers. So now instead of using the compiler's optimized type conversion you are using something that is potentially worse and guaranteed slower.

Comment: @Makogan What sort of application are you working on where you're "constantly converting between floats and integers"? It's starting to sound like you have an XY-problem.

Comment: I am reconstructing 3D geometry from 2D images using B-splines. I get information from texture coordinates (ints stored as floats), then i do a bunch of fancy math (floats). Then I have to create triangles and store these triangles in an array (ints). In order to determine the index of a triangle i need to take 2 parameters defined in the range [0,1] and then convert that to a dynamically specified offset in a 2D array. 

The code works, it;s just that it''s not compliant to my company's standards so i am trying to refactor it to make it pretty.

Comment: @Makogan If you need to constantly cast I'd argue your APIs are fscked up and *that* is the problem you *should* fix.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I ask, once more, how do i then solve the issue that I need to compute coordinates in a continuous space using floats, and then I need to use the floats to index an array? i can't avoid using floats for computations and I need an integer for indexing. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Makogan when you *have to*, use the long, explicit, ugly C++ casts. At least they are easy to find and audit and annoying to write so you only do so when you *have* to. And they are at least safer than the C-style casts.

Comment: @Makogan: using `static_cast` instead of C cast for float <-> int conversion would not make your program any safer (Jesper Juhl is wrong here. Why would it be safer? Both do the exact same thing). The only benefit that you can easily search for it, and it stands out (which can be a con as well, in my opinion. A code cluttered with `static_cast` is harder to read).

Comment: Getting the pixel-value at float coordinates very often involves interpolating as well -- this is sufficiently non-trivial to put it in a separate function (or use an existing library function). Within that function you need to do casting at some point, of course, and that should be explicitly made visible (e.g., using `static_cast`)

Comment: The last suggestion is horrible, maybe it is "short" but definitely not "elegant" or advisable in any way

Comment: The comment chain on this answer is nothing to do with the question as posted. maybe OP should post a new question that actually covers their use case

Comment: @geza: `static_cast` is safer because it won't perform as many possible casts as C-style casts. Among other things, you can't cast between pointer types (`reinterpret_cast` or C-style casts will). It's not that it's safer when the cast is intended, it's that it's less likely to silently do something you didn't intend if you misremembered your types.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a vector size , which might exceed the maximum value of `int`, in an `int` is an ugly operation in the first place.  This is reflected in your compiler warning or the fact that you have to write ugly code to suppress the warning.

The presence of the `static_cast` informs other people reading the code that there is a potential bug here, the program might malfunction in various ways if the vector size does exceed `INT_MAX`.

Obviously (I hope?) the best solution is to use the right type for the value being stored, `auto size = vector.size();`.

If you really are determined to use `int` for whatever reason then I would recommend adding code to handle the case of the vector begin too large (e.g. `throw` before the `int` declaration if it is), or add a code comment explaining why that was never possible.

With no comments, the reader can't tell if your cast was just because you wanted to shut the compiler up and didn't care about the potential bug; or if you knew what you were doing.

Comment: Arguably, having vector.size() *not* return an `difference_type` is the ugly operation, because 1) of all the implications it has on overflow possibilities and 2) of the inconsistency it creates with `vector::difference_type`. That's not changing anytime soon though.

Comment: @spectras yeah, another fail inherited from C (pointer subtraction giving signed result whilst objects can be larger than the maximum such value).